# temp array overwriting original array in loop

Tags: python, loops, temporary

I have a temporary array so that the original array won't be overwritten in each loop. I know that's not what it is actually doing, but I have no other explanation...

```
e = .95
f = .95
g = .95
h = .95

for a in range(0,10):
    e = e + .01
    for b in range(0,10):
        f = f + .01
        for c in range(0,10):
            g = g + .01
            for d in range(0,10):
                h = h + .01
                adj = []
                temp2 = original
                for x in temp2:
                    print x
                    x[0] = x[0] * e
                    x[4] = x[4] * e
                    x[1] = x[1] * f
                    x[5] = x[5] * f
                    x[2] = x[2] * g
                    x[6] = x[6] * g
                    x[3] = x[3] * h
                    x[7] = x[7] * h
                    x[8] = x[8] * e
                    x[12] = x[12] * e
                    x[9] = x[9] * f
                    x[13] = x[13] * f
                    x[10] = x[10] * g
                    x[14] = x[14] * g
                    x[11] = x[11] * h
                    x[15] = x[15] * h
                    adj.append(sum(x))
```

When I print x, it is increasing as if it is not a temporary variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`temp2` is not a separate array, it is a reference to the same array. You probably want to copy `x` into `temp2`. One way to do this would be with the following line of code:

```
import copy
temp2 = copy.deepcopy(original)
```

This assumes that this is the issue you're seeing. From your description and your code, it's not quite clear exactly what is not behaving as expected.

Answer (score 0):

The temporary array is not a separate array.
I like to fix this by creating the temporary array as an empty array first and then adding the contents of the original array to it.

This can be done like this:

```
original = ["apple", "banana", "orange"]   
tempArray = []
tempArray += original
```

Now "tempArray" will have the contents of the original array but will not overwrite "original".

Comment: This is a very rough way of creating a copy (which the accepted answer does)